# Human precursors design powered armor for invertebratre Cephalopod slaves that have lungs too, up-right or octopus-form?

Tags: creature-design, science-fiction, armors

https://ibb.co/Fqmb4tH. I couldn't use the upload option as its saying server issue. That is the picture of my cephalopod.

I'm trying to come up with an idea for power armor for my octopus species to augment its warfare capability, but I'm stuck on an interesting point.

The octopus were genetically modified to possess lungs, an extra electromagnetic brain, and greater arm and tentacle strength, as menial laborers and warriors on board spaceships and ground warfare.

We designed power armor for them, but would it be better if the power armor held them up-right as we are, placing their two tentacles in a "leg chassis" and their six arms, some either held against their body or as multiple powered arms?

Or, powered armor that allows them to be held up-right, but its main purpose is to enhance their original invertebrate physicality? I like the idea of them being held up-right to an extent but it does seem somewhat unreasonable even for science fiction.

They're typically three-feet plus, and live for 300-400 years on average.

The idea is these land-traversing octopuses rule as overlords over an area the size of China for over a thousand years with a technological edge that is running thin before they're eventually ousted by turmoil they can no longer contain. I wonder would they be more menacing and capable of taking on medieval armies if they came at humanity in their original fashion, or up-right into melee?

Comment: The answer to "Would it be better A or B?" depends, as always, on the specifics of the use case, on which you have given 0 info.

Comment: How big are they? 5 metres tall, 20 metres? Menacingness would seem to be in the eye of the beholder - which is more menacing, a clown, or a tank? Many would say the clown (even if there's one *in* the tank but unseen).

Comment: You're right I didn't provide enough, but I did mention they're 3 feet at the bottom of the questions body. I mentioned they would be fighting against humans with medieval technology outnumbered all the time. Not sure what else I'm supposed to provide, it'll modify the question when I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Robo Octobot**

[image]

Humanoid Giant Robots are a terrible idea. For details see the many questions and answers on this very site.

The reason humanoid mechs are cool is they are the same shape as people. This makes them more emotive and makes mech fights more interesting than two tanks taking turns to fire at each other.

The octopuses do not think humanoid mechs are interesting. They only have two arms. How can you hope to express yourself with only two arms?

The octopuses prefer to have octopus shaped mecha. The pilot sits in the lower section of the head part. There are eight sleeves where they put their eight tentacles to control the eight robot tentacles. Each sleeve points in the same direction as the robo-tentacle it controls.  There is a small platform in the middle where the pilot rests their mouthparts. This keeps them upright.